# Eclipse - plugin for feeding html syntax?

Tags: html, eclipse, helper

I'm trying to make use of Eclipse to be my primary tool for making websites, but I'm looking for a functionality that exists in Dreamweaver - html attributes sugestions. Is there any plugin that would enable that?
I'm already using HTML Tidy for checking the syntax. (I was going to use it to format, but I cannot get used to code being so tighthly formatted.)

Comment: What does the dreamweaver functionality does? Autocomplete? or what kind of suggestions on html attributes?

Comment: yep, autocomplete. Actually more important than html suggestions are css and JS. Do you use eclipse with such suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2)
There are few versions (2nd, 3rd, 2nd for Ruby support); the 3rd one is still beta. It can be used as it is, or can be installed as plugin for your Eclipse.
IMHO this is the best plugin if you need to use HTML/CSS/JavaScript and do it in Eclipse IDE (the reason does not matter :)

UPDATE: just forgot to mention that it has built-in support for popular JS frameworks (like YUI, jQuery, etc.).